# Is this always true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality

Suppose $\left|x_{1}\right|\ge\left|x_{2}\right|\ge\left|x_{3}\right|$, $\left|y_{1}\right|\ge\left|y_{2}\right|\ge\left|y_{3}\right|$, and $$\left(x_{1}-y_{1}\right)\left(x_{2}-y_{2}\right)\left(x_{1}-y_{2}\right)\left(x_{2}-y_{1}\right)<0,$$
is it true that $$\sqrt{\left|t\right|}+\sqrt{\left|x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}-y_{1}-y_{2}-y_{3}-t\right|}\ge\left|\sqrt{\left|x_{1}\right|}-\sqrt{\left|y_{1}\right|}\right|+\left|\sqrt{\left|x_{2}\right|}-\sqrt{\left|y_{2}\right|}\right|+\left|\sqrt{\left|x_{3}\right|}-\sqrt{\left|y_{3}\right|}\right|$$
for any $t$?

Comment: Thanks for any helpful answer!

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no to the original question (without the $(x_1-y_1)(x_2-y_2)(x_1-y_2)(x_2-y_1)<0$ restriction).  Take $t=0$, $x_1=4, x_2=x_3=1$, $y_1=y_2=y_3=2$.  The LHS is 0, while the RHS is positive.

The answer remains no with this restriction.  Take $t=0$, $x_1=7$, $x_2=5$, $x_3=0$, $y_1=6$,  $y_2=4$, $y_3=2$.  Again the LHS is 0 while the RHS is positive.

Comment: Dear vadim123, thank you for your answer, but what if $\left(x_{1}-y_{1}\right)\left(x_{2}-y_{2}\right)\left(x_{1}-y_{2}\right)\left(x_{2}-y_{1}\right)<0$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where are you getting these questions?  Perhaps if you asked what you really wanted we could help you directly.